# How to determine structure of answer for a WH-question

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, linguistics

Consider a wh-question such as "Who closed the door?". Personally, I can determine that an answer will look like "NP closed the door.", where NP would be a noun phrase. Another example is "What is John looking at?". I can determine that answer will look like "John is looking at NP".

Is there a proper way to determine structure of such answers computationally? Are there any specifications for what a proper english question must look like in terms of POS-tags?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer, but here's something to start you off.

You described the questions of interest as "wh-questions", so you may be familiar with the concept of "wh-movement". [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement) discusses it in greater detail.

If you take the rules of wh-movement and find their inverses, then you should be able to derive the answer to the wh-question (similar to how f<sup>-1</sup>(f(x)) = x).

Note that while not every linguist holds to theories of wh-movement, it's still likely to be useful in a situation such as yours, when "correct" output is more important than a "correct" theory.